# Sharepoint List integration with Microsoft Teams - Interface Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-list, microsoft-teams

I have added SharePoint List into MS Teams, but as you see the whole SharePoint page is shown.

What I want is to eliminate the red marked area and only have the list.

Is there a way to do that?

**P.S**: this happens with all list items.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How you have added the SharePoint list to Teams?

Follow below steps to add SharePoint List to Teams:

1. Open Microsoft Teams --> Select Teams tab --> Select Channel in which you want to add the SharePoint List.
2. Select **Plus (+)** sign from to bar - **Add a tab** option from top ribbon under your channel.
3. Select **SharePoint** option on the new pop up opened after click Plus (+).
4. It will show two options, **Pages** and **Lists**.
5. Select **Lists**.
6. Select the List you want to add.
7. Click Save.

It will show your list in teams like this:

[image]

Here, "TestList" is my list name.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer (which I had already done), but unfortunately it did not change anything. I am assuming that it has something to do with Settings, but it is hard to figure it out what causes this issue.

Comment: Have you followed the same steps? Or you have added it by using different steps?

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If yes, please accept it as an answer.